# DNX ASP.NET 5 publish results in error Entity Framework FileNoteFoundException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I am experimenting with asp.net 5 mvc 6 and have struck a problem which I cannot get past.

I created a project with the following structure

```
Project
|
|--Database (.net 4.5 project)
|
|--ASP.NET 5 Web Application
```

**Database Project**:

In this project I have a reference to Entity Framework 6.1.3 through NuGet and it targets the 4.5 version of .net. And it contains a `DbContext` class and a few entities

**ASP.NET 5 Web Application**:

In the ASP.NET 5 I have a reference to the database project. In this project I do the necessary hookup to `DbContext` using the standard DI with ASP.NET, for example:

```
services.AddScoped<MyDbContext, MyDbContext>();
```

I then utilise it within a controller. Very simple, all works fine when running from IIS Express or Web cmd in dev.

I then decided to publish the web site using the built in Publish feature in VS2015. I used the File System publish target. Builds with no problems.

I then run the `web.cmd` in the approot folder from command line and I get the following error:

> Application startup exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> at Community.Web.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

**Note:** if I remove the `MyDbContext` registration from the DI container, but keep the reference to the database project the error goes away.

**EDIT**:

Oh almost forgot: I am targeting only **dnx451** in project.json file within the asp.net project

Has anybody ever encountered this before?

Hooroo

Comment: I ran into this same problem, ironically enough. I created a new solution with two projects, one using net50 and one using net451. My models/views/controllers were all MVC6 in the first project, my data later was using EF6 in my net451 layer (database first model since my data was coming from existing database stored procedures). Haven't found a solution yet, but I'll follow this and answer if I discover one.

Comment: Thanks. I have not figured it out yet either. But what I did was create a solution, then add my Class Libraries (ie Domain Objects, Repositories, EF projects etc.) which target full .net. After that I added the ASP.NET 5 web site to the solution and made references to my Class Libraries and now it seems to deploy successfully. It took me a few long days to get something working :(

Comment: Curious - what does your packages folder under approot/packages/EntityFramework look like with your working app?

Comment: I found a quick, ugly work around until I can find a better way to do this - drop the EntityFramework.dll into the approot/runtimes/FRAMEWORKVERSION/bin folder. I don't think DNU and EntityFramework6 are playing well together when you publish the folders - under approot/packages it appears to be placing EF6 under a 1.0.0 folder. When you're running it locally, the dll is located under a proper 6.1.3 folder.

Comment: I'll check out the folder structure when I reach the office tomorrow morning and let you know what it looks like

Comment: folder for EF looks like this: approot\packages\EntityFramework\6.1.3, under that folder you find a content, lib and tools folder plus a .nuspec file

Comment: It looks like nuget is placing the library under approot\packages\EntityFramework\1.0.0, even though it -is- grabbing the correct version (6.1.3).